# What is the best way to save data with HTML tags in DynamoDB?

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB to store data from the form on Front-end and my data object looks like below.

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "uuid1",
    "content": "<h1>Title</h1><p>This is content</p>"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure tho if `<h1>Title</h1><p>This is content</p>` is the best way to save string with HTML tags.

What is the best way to save `<h1>Title</h1><p>This is content</p>` to DynamoDB and display back on the Front-end with HTML tags rendered properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html

### String

> Strings are Unicode with UTF-8 binary encoding. The length of a string
>   must be greater than zero and is constrained by the maximum DynamoDB
>   item size limit of 400 KB.

Since all your tags are UTF-8 compatible you don't need to do any special encoding.